# Which textbook to use with Problems and Theorems in Analysis by Pólya and Szegő?

Tags: analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm currently studying Pólya and Szegő's classic problem collection *Problems and Theorems in Analysis*. Does anyone know whether they originally wrote it with a specific analysis textbook (or series of such textbooks) in mind to be studied alongside it? If this isn't the case, which textbooks — preferably from the same era as P & S — would most closely fit the exercises? Courant perhaps?

Comment: The "Notations and Abbreviations" sections of Volumes 1 and 2 list textbooks that are "quoted repeatedly."

Comment: Thanks, I'd missed those. (Stupid me!)